# Traditional IRA to Roth IRA conversion

Tags: ira, roth-conversion

I want to convert part of my traditional IRA to Roth IRA. Where should I report it on the tax return? I read somewhere that form 8606 is to be filled out but I have not made any non-deductible contributions to a traditional IRA in previous years, and so, according to the instructions, I should not fill it out.

Comment: 8606 _part I_ is for distributions (or conversions) of trad IRA with nondeductible/posttax money. _Part II_ is for conversions of any kind of trad money. **Fill out part II**, and as instructed carry the result to 1040[SR] line 4b. Note if you do the conversion _now_ it will go on your 2020 return filed next spring. (You can't backdate a conversion to the prior year the way you can a contribution until April 15 and a removal or recharacterization until Oct. 15.)

Comment: Please turn this into an answer.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It is unfortunate that I can't back-date the conversion because I was banking on being able to do that. Next year, I might be a non-resident and so I am not sure whether I can do this conversion at all. Can I?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Can you tell me where you read this?  "You can't backdate a conversion to the prior year the way you can a contribution until April 15 and a removal or recharacterization until Oct. 15." What is with the "removal or recharacterization until Oct. 15"?

Comment: Like other tax questions, the country should be specified in the question. Second, if this is for the US, I recommend asking your brokerage - when I converted a pre-tax account to a Roth years ago, my brokerage told me everything I needed to know.

Comment: @MichaelTracy Thank you. As far as I know, Roth is peculiar to the USA..

Comment: Dave, the recharacterization is gone. There have been a number of changes in the tax code some of which were part of the large tax reform two years ago, others came piecemeal.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica: Recharacterization of Traditional IRA contributions to Roth IRA contributions and vice versa are still here. Only recharacterization to "undo" a conversion is gone.

Comment: Yes. Clearly I misunderstood his comment. Thank you for setting me straight.

Comment: user2371765: contributions can be made for a year until April 15 of following year: p590a p10 and p43; excess contributions can be removed until Oct. 15 of following year: p35 and p43/44; contributions can be recharacterized (though as user102008 notes since 2018 you can no longer use recharacterization to undo a conversion) until Oct.15: p30/31. There is no similar allowed delay for conversion, so I _didn't read_ it on p44/45. (Similarly there is no provision for distributions to be done after the end of the year.) ...

Comment: ... _IRS_ is fine with you converting as nonresident; note form 8606 also allows for carrying to 1040NR line 16b. But as nonresident you get less deductions, so you will usually owe more tax. If you don't already have the target (Roth) account, you _may_ have trouble opening one as nonresident; I'm not aware of any prohibition, but there have been numerous Qs, As, and comments here of non-US people reporting problems opening accounts at US financial institutions. The provider of your existing trad-IRA account (assuming you are satisfied with them) _should_ allow you but I can't guarantee it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you. I can simply move the money from traditional to Roth. If they have objections, they will stop me from doing it. Am I required to communicate my tax residency status to them? I have capital losses that I am hoping to write off against the transfer from traditional to Roth. If I contribute to traditional IRA in the future I suppose I will get a deduction for that too. This said, I suppose I will be losing out only on the standard deduction since I never itemized. There are no personal allowances now so there is nothing to lose there.

Comment: Yes, you should give the trustee W-8BEN to replace your previous W-9. They must withhold on normal distributions -- and if it's more than you owe you file a return for refund -- but IIUC (still) not on a trustee-to-trustee conversion. Unless 'effectively connected' to a US 'trade or business' you operate, or on real estate, or a few rare special cases, capital gains and losses for a nonresident are not US source; you don't pay US tax on gains and don't deduct losses. Do you have IRS pub 519? I recommend it; US tax for NRAs is different in _many_ ways from 'domestic'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 There are no distributions yet, and there are not likely to be in the next few years. What is IIUC? I will review Pub 519. Thank you.

Comment: IIUC = if I understand correctly. IOW (in other words), I think so but I'm not certain and you would be wise not to depend entirely on what I say. Although this could be considered redundant: you would be wise not to depend entirely on anything anyone says on the Internet, except official and verified sources -- such as IRS for US tax, and even they aren't perfect, see https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/changes-to-current-forms-publications :-}

Comment: @dave_thompson_85 Yes, I understand. Thank you. If you post your response as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.